# How to search for multiple variables within javascript file and concat?

Tags: javascript

Here is my code;

```
function concatVar(data) {
    for (var data in window) {
        if (window[data]== data.match(data+(/\[[0-9]+\]/)))
            return data;
    }
}

var data1 = [{ x: 290, y: 160}, {x: 391, y: 160}, {x: 391, y: 160}]
var data2 = [{x: 200, y: 160}, {x: 193, y: 160}, {x: 421, y: 260}]
var data3 = [{x: 200, y: 160}, {x: 193, y: 160}, {x: 421, y: 260}]

var data = data1.concat(data2, data3)

concatVar();
```

I would like to be able to search through a javascript file and find any variable named data[+numbers] and then concat them into one variable.

I'm struggling to find a way for this to be done? And I'm not sure if using a for loop within the window would be advisable?

Any advice is much appreciated!

cheers

Comment: Why use "dataX" in the first place? Why not an *array* `data` with `data[0]`, `data[1]` etc...?

Comment: This only works if the variables are global. It won't work if the interpreter is in strict mode, nor will it work if a variable is declared inside a closure.

Comment: Sorry to say, but if your site requires you to use window to pass variables around, you  have a very bad design. For this specific case, you might want to grab the Object.keys() from window, giving you an array with strings containing all the variable names as strings. You can then loop over that aarray with your regex to cehck fi it's a variable you need. Also returning inside a for-loop will end the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you should use is more likely `/var\s+data\d+\s+=\s*[\w\W]+;/ig` (which would attempt to match all the variables that look like the ones you provided).
I'd *personally* try to replace everything that is does not match that and then use another regex to extract the actual assigned values after doing some splitting to treat them one at a time: `oneOfThoseMatchedVariables.replace(/data\d+\s+=\s*/i, '')`.

`oneOfThoseMatchedVariables` should be a string looking like 
`"var data1 = [{ x: 290, y: 160}, {x: 391, y: 160}, {x: 391, y: 160}];"`

This is all assuming you already parsed the whole file you needed and have it stored to execute all this on it.